# minimum value of $(e^x - e^{-x})k + e^{-x}$

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $$ y = (e^x - e^{-x})k + e^{-x} $$
 $k$ is larger then $0$ and real value, $x$ is also real value.

$ \frac{dy}{ dx} =0$ would give the solution. But I’m curious about

1. How can I be sure that this function is convex?(What if $dy/dx=0$ point is a inflection point?)
2. How can I show there exists only one minimum value?

---

(English is not my mother tongue, so any correction would be welcomed.)

Comment: 1. second derivatie test. 2. Check all values where dy/dx = 0 and try to plot y to see if you are still missing something.

Comment: What snoram said. Also, it's _inflection_, not _infection_ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether $y$ is convex or concave depends on the values of $k$ and $x$. You want to look at the sign of $y''$:

$$y = k e^x + (1-k)e^{-x}$$

$$y' = k e^x - (1-k)e^{-x}$$

$$y'' = k e^x + (1-k)e^{-x} = y = e^{-x} \left( k e^{2x} + (1-k) \right)$$

$y$ is convex when $y'' > 0$. Assuming convexity:
$$k e^{2x} + (1-k) > 0$$
$$e^{2x} > \frac{k-1}{k}$$
$$x > \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \frac{k-1}{k} \right)$$

That's your condition for $y$ being convex at a certain $x$ for given $k$. If $y'' > 0$ for all $x$, then $y$ is convex everywhere and then you know that your local minimum is also the global minimum.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **first derivative test**. The first derivative is $y' = ke^x + ke^{-x} - e^{-x},$ and note that $y'$ and $y'e^x$ are both $>0,$ $=0,$ $<0$ for exactly the same values of $x$ since $e^x$ is positive.

Thus, the function is increasing when $ke^{2x} + k - 1 > 0,$ the function is stationary when  $ke^{2x} + k - 1 = 0,$ and the function is decreasing when $ke^{2x} + k - 1 < 0.$

Thus, the function is increasing when $x > \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-k}{k}\right),$ the function is stationary when $x = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-k}{k}\right),$ and the function is decreasing when $x < \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-k}{k}\right).$

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$y(k,x) = (e^x - e^{-x})k + e^{-x}.$$  Then $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = (e^x + e^{-x})k - e^{-x},$$ and letting $u = e^x$, finding the critical points gives us $$(u + 1/u)k = 1/u,$$ or $(u^2 + 1)k = 1$, or $u = \sqrt{1/k - 1}$, or $$x = \frac{1}{2} \log \left( \frac{1}{k} - 1 \right).$$  Consequently, there are no critical points if $1/k - 1 \le 0$, or equivalently, a critical point exists if $0 < k < 1$.  When this condition is satisfied, we can also find by taking the second derivative $$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} = (e^x - e^{-x})k + e^{-x} = y(k,x),$$ and since $0 < k < 1$, and $e^x > 0$ and $e^{-x} > 0$, it is trivial to see that this is always positive; hence $y$ is concave up and the unique critical point is a minimum.

In the animation below, the colored curves represent $(x,y(x,k))$ plotted for various values of $k$.  The solid black curve animates over $k$.  The black disk represents the minimum of $y$, and the blue bell-shaped curve is the locus of the minimum over all $k \in (0,1)$.  This locus has parametric equation $$L(k) = \left( \tfrac{1}{2}\log \left( \tfrac{1}{k} - 1 \right), 2 \sqrt{k(1-k)} \right), \quad 0 < k < 1.$$  A little algebra converts this to the equivalent function $$y = \operatorname{sech} x = \frac{2}{e^x + e^{-x}}.$$

[image]

Comment: What did you use to create this animation?

Comment: @BrianTung All animations I create for this site are done in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you write out the expression for $y'(x)$ you notice that it can only have a zero if $k<1.$ On the other hand the expression for $y''(x)$ can only be zero if $k>1.$ So even if convexity is not always guaranteed, at least it is guaranteed when the function has a zero.
2. The minimum, if it exists, is unique because all the functions involved are differentiable and the equation $y'(x)=0$ can be shown to have at most one solution.