# Find the minimum value $f(x) = \dfrac{e^x}{x^n}$ for $x>0$

Tags: calculus

> Find the minimum value $f(x) = \dfrac{e^x}{x^n}$ for $x>0$ and conclude that $f(x) > \dfrac{e^n}{n^n}$ for $x > n$.

I found the derivative $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{e^x}{x^n}\right) = e^x x^{-n-1} (x-n)$ and set it equal to zero to find that $x = n$ is the solution. Then I found the second derivative, which is $e^x x^{-2-n} (n+n^2-2 n x+x^2)$, and plugged in $x = n$ to find that it was positive implying that this is a global minimum.

Comment: ...therefore since $(n,f(n))$ is the global minimum it follows that $f(x) > f(n)$ for all $x \neq n$ so...

Comment: Comment: Students can be overenthusiastic about the second derivative test. Finding the second derivative can be troublesome, and one can make errors. Note that the **first** derivative is negative if $x\lt n$ and positive if $x\gt n$. So the function is decreasing up to $x=n$ and then increasing, so min is reached at $x=n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas An easy to prove, intuitively obvious, but seldom used fact is that if $f$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$ and increasing in $[b,c]$ then $f$ has a local minimum at $b$. But, yes, too many students insist on using the second derivative.

Comment: @ajotatxe: When I taught calculus (probably about 30 times between the mid 1980s and mid 2000s), it seemed that the 2nd derivative test was almost never easier than an intelligent application of the 1st derivative test. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559912/minimum-value-of-ex-e-xk-e-x/1559940#1559940) and [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/plaintext.jspa?messageID=5324603).

Answer (score 1):

A preliminary remark: note that the result is false for $n<0$ (because $f(x)$ assumes arbitrarily large negative values for small negative $x$ if $n$ is odd). You might think $n>0$ was implicit, but a careful reading shows it is not. [Thanks to @BarryCipra]

However, let us assume that $n>0$.

Yes, your proof is partially correct. To finish off you need to note that since $f(x)$ has a global minimum at $x=n$ we have $f(x)>f(n)$ for all $x>0$. [Thanks to @user1892304]

But it is not enough to find that the 2nd derivative is positive at a zero of the first derivative. That might or might not indicate a global minimum. To establish a global minimum at $x=n$ you need that the 1st derivative is $<0$ for $x<n$ and $>0$ for $x>n$. It is easy to see directly from the expression for the 1st derivative that this is true here. [Thanks to @AndreNicholas]

Alternatively, note that $n+n^2-2nx+x^2=n+(n-x)^2>0$ so that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x$, not just $f''(n)>0$. [Thanks to @BarryCipra]

The plot shows the case $n=3$

[image]

Comment: @BarryCipra Why not edit this directly. I am just trying to reduce the flood of unanswered questions answered in comments.

Comment: Wait, a critical point at which the second derivative is positive must be a local minimum!

Comment: But not necessarily a global minimum.

Comment: Agreed.  The OP really needs to note that $n+n^2-2nx+x^2=n+(n-x)^2\gt0$ so that $f''(x)\gt0$ for all $x$, not just $f''(n)\gt0$.  (By the way, the problem tacitly assumes $n\gt0$, since the statement isn't true for $n\lt0$.)

Comment: You could also use this result: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725688

Comment: @user84413 That result looks false to me! I doubt it is enough for $f$ to be continuous or even differentiable. Doesn't the result depends on the derivative being continuous, so that in order to "turn up" after (or before) the local maximum it has another local extremum?

Comment: @almagest I am pretty sure this result is correct, since it seems clear intuitively and the proof given seems fine.  (I read it with some skepticism, since I thought differentiability was probably required.)  If you find a problem with it, though, I would be interested to know.

Comment: @user84413 Yes you are right. The point, of course, is that the definition of "local maximum" makes no mention of derivatives. It is just that there is a small interval around the point where the function is no bigger. So it is trivial to extend that to a global maximum by compactness. But this OP and umpteen math undergraduates do not think of local maximum in those terms, they think of it in terms of first or even second derivative.

Comment: @almagest Thanks for checking this, and for letting me know. (I have to admit that sometimes I also make this mistake of thinking in terms of the derivatives instead of the definition itself.)